# Building a City/Country Search box. Can Bing API support this?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api, azure-maps

I'm currently building a search box for a mobile app that can search for a Country/ State/ Country. I'm currently looking for APIs that can support this... An option for me would be the Google Places API but as much as possible I don't want to use Google for my project.

So before I import the Bing SDK into my project, I'm curious if anyone knows if this is possible with Bing API.

Answer (score 0):

With Bing Maps you can use the location query API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/find-a-location-by-query however, it will also find addresses if you pass them in. Generally though, if you type just a state or country, this API will return the expected result. You can add a bit of code to look through the results and filter them based on their entity type if required.

Since you tagged Azure Maps, you can use the Azure Maps address search API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/get-search-address It has filtering parameters available that might be better suited for this scenario.